# String cannot be cast to an Iterable error?

Tags: maven, groovy, iterator, guava

So I'm attempting to go through a groovyObject's fields and obtain the property of that field. So this is what I got(sorry its a little rough so cleaning would be appreciated but not necessary, I'm also doing a little debugging and other stuff with the Log and what not.):

```
public void traverse(final GroovyObject groovy) throws RepositoryException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException 
{       
    Field[] theFields = groovy.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    final ArrayList<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
    int count =0;
    for(Field field : theFields)
    {
        fields.add(field);
        LOG.error("{} = {}",field.getName(), groovy.getProperty(field.getName()));  

    }



//this is the guava tree traverser      
TreeTraverser<GroovyObject> traverser = new TreeTraverser<GroovyObject>()
        {

        @Override
        public Iterable<GroovyObject> children(GroovyObject root)
        {               

            return (Iterable<GroovyObject>)root.getProperty(fields.get(0).getName());
 //|-->Here I get the String cannot be cast to Iterable. Which I find odd since it is still an object just getProperty takes a string. right?

        }

    };
```

Thoughts on this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`GroovyObject.getProperty(String)` retrieves the value of the given property. And if that value happens to be a `String` you cannot cast it to `Iterable`.

If you adjust your log statement, you can inspect the types of the fields:

```
LOG.error("{} of type {} = {}", field.getName(), field.getType(), groovy.getProperty(field.getName()));
```

Comment: How would you suggest I begin to create this tree traversal? Rather than GroovyObject should I set the type to Field?

Comment: Perhaps would creating a string iterator and giving getProperty(stringIterator.next()) solve my problems?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it outl. Essentially what needs to happen is I need to make two iterators: one for the groovy objects and one for the property strings so the end goal looks like

```
groovyObject.iterate().next().getProperty(string.iterate().next());
```

Or something like that, *I will update this when I figure it out.!*

Once I make that I can go back in and think about making it more efficient